# changing display property of a divider in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this program in HTML (with of course CSS and JS) but I am having troubles with some code cause I want to make an area be managable so that you can make it visible, and invisible when ever you want. if you dont get what I mean, I will just show you in code.

```js
//browserSearching.js
// First, the variables!
 var link = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
 var page = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").src;

 var button = {
  menu: document.getElementById("dropdown"),
  enter: document.getElementById("enter"),
  back: document.getElementById("back"),
  forward: document.getElementById("forward")
 }

 var more = document.getElementById("more");

 // Now it is time for functions!

 function enableMore() {
  if (more.style.display == "block") {
   more.style.display == "none"
  } else {
   more.style.display == "block"
  }
 }

 function update() {
  link = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;

  setTimeout(update, 1);
 }
```

```css
// style.css
#splitter {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

// This part is not really needed
```

```html
<!--Indext.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Web Browser in Web Browser</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <script src="data.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px;" onload="update();">
   <browser>
   <div id="top">

    <!-- First Layer -->
    <div id="tabs">
     <tab></tab>
    </div>
    <br /><!-- Second Layer --> <hr />
    &#160;
    <button id="back">&#60;</button>
    <button id="forward">&#62;</button>
    <button id="home">H</button>

    <input id="searchbar" style="width: 1107px;" />
    <button id="enter" onclick="page = link;">Ent</button>

    <button id="dropdown" onclick="enableMore();"> : </button>

    <div id="more" style="display: none;">

     <!-- This is all one button, and it was hard! -->
     <label for="themes" class="button">Upload CSS Theme</label>
     <input id="themes" style="display: none;" type="file" />
     <!-- End of the button -->
    </div>
   </div>
   <hr id="splitter"/>
   <iframe name="webpage" src="browser.html" width="1277.5px" height="640px" style="border-width: 0px;"></iframe>
  </browser>
  <script src="browserSearching.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

do you get what I am trying to say now? just press the [:] button... it doesn't show anything when pressed

Comment: can you mention your file names in the code snippet ??

Comment: No JavaScript errors in F12 tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `enableMore()` function, you're doing a comparison, when you need to do an assignment.

Change your `==` to `=` as follows:

```
function enableMore() {
    if (more.style.display == "block") {
        more.style.display = "none" // Double-equals changed to single
    } else {
        more.style.display = "block" // Double-equals changed to single
    }
}
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgBegX?editors=1000#0)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise they were == instead of =!